# Is there any shorthand in C# to make a setter additionally set a dirty flag

Tags: c#, setter

Currently in order to make a setter also set a [dirty property](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/dirty-flag.html) I have to do something like this:

```
private bool _isDirty;
private int _lives;
public int Lives{
    get { return _lives; }
    set {
        if (_lives != value){
            _lives = value;
            _isDirty = true;
        }
    }
}
```

It's not a huge pain to write but it's a very vertically spacious and repetitive piece of code to write if I use quite a lot of this pattern in my project.

Is there any shorthand or alternative, shorter syntax to do that in C#?

**What I am specifically trying to accomplish** is that certain variables changing should trigger a dirty flag, which on the render phase of the code can be used to refresh the properties of the rendered object.

Comment: Maybe Postsharp and AOP might be an option.

Comment: It´s clear, understandable and does what you want, doesn´t it? Concentrate on your real problems... If you find yourself writing that code again and again you should refactor it into an own method.

Comment: Look into INotifyPropertyChanged.  It's not a perfect solution but with enough wrangling around and some reflection it can get you into the land of one-liners.  You can use the same concept to apply to this.

Comment: @HimBromBeere "repetitive piece of code to write if I use quite a lot of this pattern in my project." Arguably that would be a problem if it was repeated a whole bunch of times throughout the project.

Comment: @HimBromBeere You're not wrong, but just because there are more important things to take care of does not mean I have to ignore everything else, and this specific thing is like a sore thumb to me. Perhaps I should solve it in a meta way by writing a live template I can quickly insert.

Comment: What do you mean by "this pattern"? Can you add another example for it so we get a better understanding of what exactly you consider to be repetitive?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Sure, I've added explanation about what I am trying to accomplish - in short a flag which indicates some properties have been changed and a later process needs to refresh its state based on those properties.

Comment: In Visual Studio you can create snippets (templates) to make writing repetitive code easier.

Comment: You *could* achieve this by creating a method accepting the property-name of the getter. There set the flklag and call the getter via reflection. However I doubt this will make youe code smarter or even shorter, in particular you have to write something like `SetValue("Lives", value)` in *every*  getter, which doesn´t seem better to me. Furthermore relying on reflection is often a bad design.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: your `SetValue` call can be simplified with a `CallerMemberName` attribute, so setters don't need to pass in their name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a Class where you implement a helper method.

```
class DirtyClass
{
  protected bool IsDirty { get; set;}

  protected void ChangeProperty<T>(ref T backing, T Value)
  { 
      if(!backing.Equals(value))
      {
           backing = value;
           IsDirty = true;
      }
  }
}
```

USe the helper method in the setter

```
class LivesCounter : DirtyClass
{
   private int _lives;
   public int Lives  
   {
      get { return _lives; }
      set { ChangeProperty(ref _lives, value); }
   }
}
```

Handling null elements is left as an exercise.

As jdl134679 has mentioned, look into the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: _Handling null elements is left as an exercise._ Use [object.Equals(obj, obj)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of _backing.Equals_. That handles null values and forwards to Equals if the instance isn't null.

Comment: Maybe it's an option to change the name of the method to `ChangeField` because it doesn't change the property. I like this way of implementing that behaviour. Adding INotifyPropertyChanged would be pretty easy using that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the classes way you could also create a snippet.
info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165396.aspx

create a snippet by hand: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx

OR

install snippet designer https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/B08B0375-139E-41D7-AF9B-FAEE50F68392

create a snippet and name it propisd (property shortcut)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>Properties with Dirty</Title>
            <Author>Myself</Author>
            <Description>Creates a property which ties to isDrty</Description>
            <Shortcut>propisd</Shortcut>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Code Language="C#">
                <![CDATA[private $TYPE$ $PRIVATENAME$;
                    public $TYPE$ $PROPERTYNAME$
                    {
                        get { return $PRIVATENAME$; }
                        set 
                        {
                            if ($PRIVATENAME$ != value)
                            {
                                $PRIVATENAME$ = value;
                                _isDirty = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }]]>
            </Code>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>TYPE</ID>
                    <ToolTip>replace with the type</ToolTip>
                    <Default>"TYPE"</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>PRIVATENAME</ID>
                    <ToolTip>replace with the private name</ToolTip>
                    <Default>"PRIVATENAME"</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>PROPERTYNAME</ID>
                    <ToolTip>replace with the property name</ToolTip>
                    <Default>"PROPERTYNAME"</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

save this file as propisd.snippet and add it via the snippet manager.

Whenever you type propisd followed by TAB you will see the snippet. By using Tab you will go through the replacements. Like you would type 'prop' and then do TAB.

Answer (score 0):

No - you could make your own struct in order to encapsulate this behavior, ie. a generic struct holding a value, an IsDirty property and a way of clearing the flag.